# Custom field in event - for the message templates

Tags: civievent, custom-fields, message-templates

In the Event Information I have new field. There, the organizer can be selected from the CRM. For the message templates I would like to use this information. If the field is filled, the First name / Email / Phone field of the address should appear in the message.
- Where can I find necessary examples and information? Thanks Felix
Wordpress 5.3 / CiviCRM 5.19